# How to add child object in parent view

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

currently i ask myself how i can achieve to add child objects in a parent view in ASP.NET Core. I'm a nooby and for this question i create a example project. In this project i have the following models

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What i want to achieve is that i can create Tags for a blog inline of creating or editing a blog like e.g.

Inline editing example

[image]

Comment: Define `child objects` and `parent view` please!

Comment: I think you need a foreign key property on Tag class which is "BlogId" to build a relation between Blog and Tag.